# What is the difference between Queue.from and Queue.of?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the [Queue.from](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/Queue/Queue.from.html) and [Queue.of](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/Queue/Queue.of.html) (or [ListQueue.from](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/ListQueue/ListQueue.from.html) and [ListQueue.of](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/ListQueue/ListQueue.of.html)). Both the descriptions and implementations look very similar, yet slightly different.

Is there any potential reason to use one or the other?

Comment: There are an answer here for `List.from` vs `List.of` but the answer is kinda the same: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45840#issuecomment-827497363

Comment: Yup, that actually answers my question! In short - 1) `of` is safer and therefore preferred, 2) the difference between them is poorly documented but there's an open issue for it already. Thanks!

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result